# CSS tile flip on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some Div Boxes how can i get them flipped on hover? I tried already some examples i found but i cant get it working? Can someone please help me?

```css
.kachel_a_image_1 {
 height:150px;
 width:150px;
 margin:auto auto;
 margin-top:15px;
 background:red;
}

.kachel_wrapper {
    margin: auto auto;
    width: 90%;
    min-height: 450px;
    margin-top: 55px;
    text-align: center;
   padding:10px;
 padding-top:30px;
 padding-bottom:20px;
}

.kachel_text {
 font-size:10px;
 color:white;
line-height:15px;
  text-align:center;
 }

.kachel {
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 58px;
  background: #6e7176;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="kachel"><div class="kachel_a_image_1"></div><div class="kachel_text">Social</div></div>
```

I only want to use Css and no JS if its possible. Can someone explain me how this works or giving me a really simple example :S ?

Comment: How do you want your box to be flipped?

Comment: kacheln is a german word bro :'D

Comment: @messerbill ye wasnt known the word in English xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using `transition` and `backface-visibility`.

Probably the best soultion is to use simple transform and `backface-visibility`. **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ev4tb8ay/1/)**

```css
.front, .back{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.front{
  background-color: blue;
}
.back{
  background-color: red;
      background-image: url("https://yt3.ggpht.com/-Bvvd30cZJe4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/CxN5F1_QEU8/s100-c-k-no/photo.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
 perspective: 1000;
}
 /* flip the pane when hovered */
 .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
 transition: 0.6s;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;

 position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
 backface-visibility: hidden;

 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
 z-index: 2;
 /* for firefox 31 */
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
 <div class="flipper">
  <div class="front">
  </div>
  <div class="back">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

### Using `@-webkit-keyframe`

Another approach is to use `animation` and `@-webkit-keyframes`. However this will run the animation one time initially. ([**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ev4tb8ay/3/))

```css
.box, .wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-animation: in 0.2s forwards;
  animation in 1s forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.front {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-animation: out 0.2s forwards;
  animation out 0.2s forwards;
  background-image: url("https://yt3.ggpht.com/-Bvvd30cZJe4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/CxN5F1_QEU8/s100-c-k-no/photo.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.wrapper:hover .box.back {
  -webkit-animation: out 0.2s forwards;
  animation: out 0.2s forwards;
}

.wrapper:hover .box.front {
  -webkit-animation: in 0.2s forwards;
  animation: in 0.2s forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes in {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes out {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box back"></div>
  <div class="box front"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you edit a bit so on Mouse leave its smooth ? xD

Comment: Yeah, gave you 2 other options.

Answer (score 5):

Use **transform**:

```
.kachel:hover{
    transform: rotateX(150deg);
}
```

more Information: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_3dtransforms.asp

Also if you want to add a duration to the animation use **transition-duration**

```
.kachel{
    transition-duration: 5s;
}
```

for changing the content after the hover use the pseudo element **:after** and the attribute **content**.
For example:

```
.kachel:hover:after{
    content: 'hovering';
}
```

You may have to change it a bit, i haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks :) but no wi have still the same content showing. How can i show then some different content ?

Answer (score 1):

For this I would use `backface-visibility` in conjunction with `transform`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box front">image</div>
    <div class="box back">Social</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s linear;
  transition: all .4s linear;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front {
  background: red;
  z-index: 2;
}

.back {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  color:white;
}

.container:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

**[Here's a JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhj2mt3z/3/)**

EDIT: The above fiddle has been edited to have an outer wrapper which initiates the flip. This ensures that the animation doesn't jitter.

```
.wrapper {
    width: 180px;
}
.wrapper:hover .container {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i want and its working in my Scripts but is there a solve for this "" shaking" bug "" :/ ?